# Setting Replicate API Token - Syntax Error

Tags: authentication, token, replicate

pip install replicate

import os
os.environ["REPLICATE_API_TOKEN"] = "<r8_N9dOSgxqFL3hdOry9uXXXXXXX>"

Then when I execute I have this message : "ReplicateError: You did not pass an authentication token"

Do you guys know howto solve this error please ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.